# Problem with non-existent package 'kdl'

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made the ros_package "cob_people_detection" in groovy and I got an error.

```
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'cob_people_detection' depends on non-existent package 'kdl' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'cob_people_detection'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosbuild_init)
```

I have already installed the ros-groovy-kdl, but the error still exist. WHY?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129426/problem-with-non-existent-package-%27kdl%27/) by [Jianyuan Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/11541/jianyuan-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like ros-groovy-kdl is simply a wrapper around orocos_kdl and python_orocos_kdl (which are now system level dependencies, rather than ROS packages), I'm guessing that cob_people_detection hasn't been  updated for this.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0